# simple_form or formtastic Input type for hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, formtastic, hstore

Does anybody know any simple_form or formtastic input for hstore?
I tried to search for any input but I didn't find any yet... It seems that the hstore field type is not yet supported...

I would need it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use like this for input as hstore:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
   <%= f.simple_fields_for :attributes do |d| %>
       <% f.object.attributes.try(:each) do |key, value| %>
          <%= d.input key, :input_html => {:value => value } %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not supported directly. But you can do something like this

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :settings do |setting| %>
    <%= setting.input :color, :input_html => { :value => <value> } %>
    <%= setting.input :height, :input_html => { :value => <value> } %>
<% end %>
```